# Weird navbar stutter with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On [this website](https://haxholmweb.dk/), I have a navbar at the top.
Now, using jQuery, I make the navbar smaller by adding a CSS-class called .shrink
when scrollTop is more than 100px.
The functionality itself works fine. The class gets applied and the navbar gets smaller, but I am facing a stutter issue. If you scroll a little from the top (I believe around 100px), the navbar starts to jump up and down all crazy. I have no idea what causes the issue nor do I know how to fix it. Anybody know a solution?

```js
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $("header").addClass("shrink");
  } else {
    $("header").removeClass("shrink");
  }
});
```

```css
header.is-fixed {
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 9999;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 1.5rem 0;
  transition: 0.2s;
  background-color: #333;
}

header.shrink {
  padding: 0.75rem 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="is-fixed">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
      Content here
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<div style="height:2000px; background-color:red">
</div>
```

Comment: Not seeing a problem. Which browser?

Comment: Google Chrome. I just tried in Edge and it doesn't seem to persist there.

Comment: Not seeing it in chrome either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this bug its most likely to appear when you use a very sensitive scroll peripheral, like mac trackpad.
Using a normal mouse wheel reduce this chance by a lot.

Now the code.

You need to use position:fixed; on the navbar, because position sticky somehow changes the scrollTop calculation it self, making the comprobation enter in some kind of loop, in adition to position fixed, you need to take account of the offset of your content at scroll position 0, since position fixed does not push the next child down, use a margin top or something

I already, made a test with chrome inspector on your site, changing
'header.is-fixed' to position fixed and adding 102px margin to firts section with this class
'hero is-medium has-text-centered-mobile has-bg-img has-text-centered'
and no more bug

Hope this helps

Comment: Wonderful! That completely solved the issue. So it seems to be something that persists exclusively when using position:sticky. Using position:fixed was the solution here.